# Possible autologin in web app via Facebook button if user has installed Facebook mobile application on this phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

Whether it is possible to use (to obtain) data of the user for automatic authorization in a web application through facebook login the button without repeated data input , if the user became authorized in facebook through Facebook mobile application on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at using Facebook's Android API for this. It enables you to let people login to your app through Facebook, and provide permissions to it as you need (like accessing friends, or account information).

You will need to create a developer account with Facebook. The link below should get you well on the way.

[Facebook Android API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)